# Server 2019 FSRM quota deleted still running

Tags: windows-server-2019

I added the FSRM role to the fileserver yesterday and created a quota.  However the quota was too low and was applied to every directory.  I deleted the quota without disabling it.  It is out of the list but still is being enforced.

I had another admin look at it, and he changed all the ownerships of the directories in an attempt to resolve it.

After that, I'm now getting an error, and the quota was still applied.

The quota was still applied after deletion, and only dropped off once I removed the role of FSRM.

This is the error:

```
File Server Resource Manager
An unexpected error has occurred.  Please check application event log for more information.

Details:
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
(E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Obviously, this error comes from him changing the ownerships, but I have changed them back.

The quota was still applied after deletion, and only dropped off once I removed the role of FSRM.

Now when I add the role back, it enforces the quota as soon as FSRM runs, and still isn't in the quota list.  I immediately get the error as soon as FSRM opens.

Here are the Event Logs:

Warning:

```
File Server Resource Manager was unable to access the following file or volume: '\\?\Volume{80d2283d-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\System Volume Information\SRM\FciNrt.usn'.  This file or volume might be locked by another application right now, or you might need to give Local System access to it.
```

Error:

```
An unexpected error occurred in the File Server Resource Manager MMC snap-in
   at Microsoft.Storage.SrmMmc.QuotaDataCache.Enumerate(RemoteManager remoteManager, SrmDataCacheEnumEventHandler EventHandler, Int32 BatchSize)
   at Microsoft.Storage.SrmMmc.QuotasDisplayArea.EnumerateItemsIntoListView()
   at Microsoft.Storage.SrmMmc.DisplayArea.SafeEnumerateItemsIntoListView()
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.Storage.IFsrmQuotaManager.EnumQuotas(String Path, _FsrmEnumOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Storage.SrmMmc.QuotaDataCache.Enumerate(RemoteManager remoteManager, SrmDataCacheEnumEventHandler EventHandler, Int32 BatchSize)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add I tried
>dirquota quota scan /path:E:
and
>Remove-FsrmQuota E:
and returned no results